# Identify and plot differences between two shapefiles using sf and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, r-sf

I have two shapefiles that show old and new municipality borders. Some municipalities were combined, others were divided.

I would like to **show the differences** between the two, that is, which municipalities have been merged and which have been divided into smaller units. The shapefiles contain sfc_multipolygons.

I figured out how to display the new divisions (use and plot st_sym_difference, then plot one of the original shapefiles as layer 2). I also managed to show the merged municipalities by plotting the old borders first and the new borders as a second layer.

However, I can't figure out how to combine everything in one plot, that is, things that haven't changed in black, borders that have been removed in blue, and newly created borders in red.

Any pointers and tips are highly appreciated!

Comment: It might be easier to help if you post your data or part of it.